# Associating properties to Class objects

Tags: python, class, metaprogramming

I would like to define properties for classes, and be able to access them before I actually instantiate an object of that class.

I'll give some context. My application handles a library of components. Each component is mapped to a Python class. Now I want to know what configuration a component needs, before actually instancing the class.

One solution is to write something like this:

```
class Component:
    @classmethod
    def config(cls, name, description, default=None):
        ''' Define one configuration switch for the class. '''
        # now put this information in a class-specific dictionary

class Model1(Component):
    @classmethod
    def define_configuration(cls):
        cls.config('n', 'number of burzs to instigate')
        cls.config('skip', 'skip any barzs among the burzs', default=True)
    # ...

component_class = Model1
component_class.define_configuration()
```

However, it seems pretty ugly. Ideally I would like to be able to write something like the following, and still be able to put the configuration switches in a class-specific dictionary to be accessed later.

```
class Model1(Component):
    config('n', 'number of burz to instigate')
    config('skip', 'skip any barz in the data', default=True)
```

My initial solution was to write something like:

```
class Model1(Component):
    Model1.config('n', 'number of burz to instigate')
    Model1.config('skip', 'skip any barz in the data', default=True)
```

however I discovered on other questions here on SO that the class name is not defined yet when the body is executed.

What should I do?

tl;dr: How can I get a nice syntax for defining class-specific properties (before I instance an object of that class)?

---

Here is (for the record) the solution that was suggested (a bit elaborated).
Yai! I could get exactly what I wanted. :-)

```
from collections import namedtuple
Config = namedtuple('Config', 'name desc default')

def config(name, description, default=None):
    ComponentMeta.tmp_config_storage.append(Config(name, description, default))

class ComponentMeta(type):
    tmp_config_storage = []
    def __init__(cls, clsname, bases, clsdict):
        for config in ComponentMeta.tmp_config_storage:
            if not 'my_config' in cls.__dict__:
                setattr(cls, 'my_config', [])
            cls.my_config.append(config)
        ComponentMeta.tmp_config_storage = []

class Component(object):
    __metaclass__ = ComponentMeta

class Model1(Component):
    config('x1', 'for model1')
    config('y1', 'for model1')

class Model2(Component):
    config('x2', 'for model2')

print 'config for Model1:', Model1.my_config
print 'config for Model2:', Model2.my_config
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to need to use `self` somewhere in there. 

But I don't get why you use two calls to the config method?

Comment: @vlad He uses two calls because he wants to add two items. each call adds one. Also, you see `cls` instead of `self` because these are class methods that operate on the class instead of on an instance.

Comment: Oh. I get what he meant with the 'class-specific dictionary' now.

Comment: you might want to move the check `if not 'my_config' in cls.__dict__` before the `for` loop so it doesn't execute every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### corrected

```
def config(name, description, default=None):
    ComponentMeta.config_items.append((name, description, default))

class ComponentMeta(type):
    config_items = []
    def __init__(cls, clsname, bases, clsdict):
        for options in ComponentMeta.config_items:
                cls.add_config(*options)
        ComponentMeta.config_items = []

class Component(object):
    __metaclass__ = ComponentMeta
    config_items = [] # this is only for testing. you don't need it
    @classmethod
    def add_config(cls, name, description, default=None):
        #also for testing
        cls.config_items.append((name, description, default))

class Model1(Component):
    config('n', 'number of burz to instigate')
    config('skip', 'skip any barz in the data', default=True)

print Model1.config_items
```

This works by making config an external function that adds the items to `ComponentMeta.config_instances`. `ComponentMeta` then checks this list when creating a class and calls `config_item` on the items. Note that this is not thread safe (although it could me made so). Also, if a subclass of `ComponentMeta` fails to call `super` or empty `ComponentMeta.config_items` itself, the next created class will get the config items.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't seem to work though.

I think I understand the philosophy, but I don't understand how in these lines: '''

    class Model1(Component):
        config('n', 'number of burz to instigate')
        config('skip', 'skip any barz in the data', default=True)

''' where two config objects are created, how do the objects get put in the class dictionary?

Comment: @Anrdea. Correct. I'm sorta embarrassed about that actually. See my most recent update which gives you exactly what you want modulo a few potential problems. See the answer for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see that the trick that I would never have found by myself is to put something in a temp storage area, and then reset it each time a class is defined.

Comment: @Andrea Glad I could help. Note that you might want to make `config` a class method of `ComponentMeta` (perhaps renamed to `Component` with `Component` renamed to `ComponentBase`. This makes it a little more clear that it's only to be used in the context of creating a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

A class name is defined once the body is executed. This happens when the file containing the class is imported. This is not the same as creation of an instance of a class.

```
class A(object):
    """ doc """
    config = []
    def __init__(def):
        pass
A.config.append(('n', 'number of burz to instigate'))
A.config.append(('skip', 'skip any barz in the data', default=True))
# access class specific config before object instantiation
x = A.config[0]
# instantiating your class, post configuration access
a_obj = A()
```

Wouldn't this approach serve your purpose? The class config can be stored in a class variable which can be modified and added before you instantiate any objects of this class.

Using class variables should serve your purpose.

Comment: you don't have to call append: you can just make `config` a list literal during class creation.

Comment: Yes, that's another solution. I was wondering if it could be made less verbose. (also esthetically I'd prefer the config to be in the class definition)

Answer (score 1):

Why not something simple like, say:

```
def makeconfigdict(cls):
    thedict = {}
    for name, value in cls.__dict__.items():
       if isaconfig(value):
           addconfigtodict(thedict, name, value)
           delattr(cls, name)
    cls.specialdict = thedict
    return cls

@makeconfigdict
class Model1(Component):
    n = config('number of burz to instigate')
    skip = config('skip any barz in the data', default=True)
    ...
```

As long as the `config` function returns objects that an `isaconfig` function can recognize, and an `addconfigtodict` function can properly set into the special dictionary in whatever format you want, you're in clover.

If I understand your specs correctly you **don't** want a normal attribute like `Model1.skip`, right?  That's why I have that `delattr` call in `makeconfigdict` (and also why I use `.items()` on the class's dictionary -- since the dictionary is modified during the loop, it's better to use `.items()`, which takes a "snapshot" list of all names and values, rather than the usual `.iteritems()`, which just iterates on the dictionary, thus **not** allowing it to be modified during the loop).

Comment: Thanks Alex for this answer. That's an alternative. Yes, I don't want also a normal attribute. I guess I'll use the other solution proposed, which is 'hacky' in other ways, but it seems more user friendly (the user might expect that Model1.skip refers to something).